# How To group product price as range and list in navigation as shop by price using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
SELECT price_range, count(*) AS num
FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN product_price >= 150 AND product_price <= 249.99 THEN '150-249.99'
         WHEN product_price >= 250 AND product_price <= 299.99 THEN '250-299.99'
         WHEN product_price >= 300 AND product_price <= 399.99 THEN '300-399.99'
         WHEN product_price >= 400 AND product_price <= 499.99 THEN '400-499.99'
         WHEN product_price >= 500 AND product_price <= 999.99 THEN '500-999.99'
         ELSE 'over 1000'
     END as price_range
FROM washing_machines
WHERE 1
) AS  price_summaries
GROUP BY price_range
```

Can any one explain this with an example?

Comment: Maybe you could provide the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple query. 
If you have a table with several price you select the price_range and the number of occurrency of each price_range.

The price_range is calculated by a select with `CASE` and for each `WHEN` staement  you get a different price_range.

I hope this could be useful for you